# Should a win32 program always be multi-threaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, opengl

Right now I am writing a win32 / opengl application that has 2 threads per window. One thread deals with opengl drawing, the other deals with the windows message events. My question is, should I only use 1 thread for ALL windows messages? Will that cause problems such as windows not responding occasionally?

I'm using multiple windows message loops, all on different threads. It seems to me that the message loop was designed for 1 thread, and only one appearance in a process. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> should I only use 1 thread for ALL windows messages?

You may, or nay. It is not enforced by the OS, but it may be by your GUI framework.

> Will that cause problems such as windows not responding occasionally?

It will not, in itself, cause that problem.  Poorly-responding message-loops are usually caused by performing too much work in wndprocs/event-handlers for windows that handle messages from the OS UI drivers, or actually waiting in them for something instead of returning to the GetMessage call in a timely manner.  The OS detects that messages from KB etc. are not getting handled, and tends to ghost the window and generally moan about a 'Not responding' application.

IF a WMQ is used to communcate with a thread that does not process UI messages, eg, those with message number WM_APP upwards, the OS will take no action if the thread handling such messages performs lengthy and/or blocking actions before getting back to its GetMessage call.

> It seems to me that the message loop was designed for 1 thread, and
>   only one appearance in a process. Is this correct?

No, it is not.

Windows Message Queues, and associated GetMessage() loops, can be, and often are, used to communicate between threads of a process.  WMQ are specialised producer-consumer queues, primarily designed to communicate GUI messages.  As such, they have constraints on message format, and only one thread can wait on a queue, but WMQ can be used to communicate between non-GUI threads.

It is correct that windows are bound to the threads that create them, and that many GUI framewoks are designed/written in such a way that it is not safe to use them from multiple threads, but many Windows message queues and message-handlers in one process are certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation dependent. Multi-threading makes often sense if to independent processes shouldn't disturb the program flow. However there are other ways to achieve similar things too. E.g. you could use timers to break the flow for a couple of ms and execute what the other thread would do.

If you would recognize that your window event thread is getting on it's limits, than I would think first, that you probably are not doing event handling only but also greater calculations. There it would make sense to start a new thread.

**Edit: I am not a windows pro. But nearly all implementations I know use for the event system only one thread (loop). Qt has some elegant ways to circumvent breaks and to extent the event system by spawning new threads in different ways. It also supports Signal/Slots in combination with timers. Maybe you are interested to use it.**